# How to make left outer join group in 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

Need to group 2 tables which have left outer join relation.

```
 select * from Sites
 LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteToEmps ON Sites.Id = SiteToEmps.SiteId 
 GROUP BY Sites.Id
```

I need the write syntax.

Comment: The syntax is fine. Some other parts may not be (depending on the database), but your question is lacking all relevant information. Please read again [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question, and amend your question with relevant details.

Comment: A group by make sense if you use a grouping function, lile sum, max or count. In your case ( if you were added all the fields to the group by) it does exactly the same than a distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main trick is "whichever non-aggregated column included in the `group by` list, should be included in the `select` list, too" such as

```
SELECT s.Id
  FROM Sites s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteToEmps e
    ON s.Id = e.SiteId
 GROUP BY s.Id
```

Comment: Although this resolves the error, the query would return the same whether the `LEFT JOIN` is there or not. I suspect we're missing a key piece of information.

Answer (score 2):

You should either include all the fields in both table in `GROUP BY` syntax.
It will be something like this:

```
 select * from Sites
 LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteToEmps ON Sites.Id = SiteToEmps.SiteId 
 GROUP BY Sites.Id, Field2, Field3, Field4
```

Or you should write any field you want to include in `GROUP BY` syntax, instead of `*`. It will be something like this:

```
select Sites.Id from Sites
LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteToEmps ON Sites.Id = SiteToEmps.SiteId 
GROUP BY Sites.Id
```